# display Scheduler with Current date and with fixed time in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am working with ExtJS MVC and implementing Scheduler.

I need your help to display **Scheduler with Current date and with fixed time.**
like 
Today is 13-3-2012. so I want to display day wise scheduler with 13-03 but time is fixed like from 9am to 6pm.

I am able to archive to display current date but I Don't know how to set time..

```
var start = Ext.Date.clearTime(new Date()),
```

using this current date is display but how can i set time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **setHours method** we can set hours in current date.

For more http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date